# W3WP recycle return codes

Tags: iis-6, iis

I have an IIS6 machine, running multiple web applications. Once in a while, IIS recycles W3WP.
When i look at the error codes, W3WP.exe usually exits with return code -2 (0xfffffffe) but one in a while it exits with -3 (0xfffffffd). While the end result is the same, i was wondering if there's any difference/reason to these particular return codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2007/03/22/how-to-troubleshoot-an-iis-event-id-1009-error.aspx), -3 indicates that WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) had to kill a worker process, whereas -2 means that the process closed OK.

So I suspect that when you see -3, it means that the worker process was doing something at the time it was recycled, but -2 means the worker process wasn't busy and was OK with just quitting when asked.

Answer (score 0):

- A return code of 0xFFFFFFFF means that the worker process exited due to a fatal error.
- A return code of 0xFFFFFFFE means that the worker process exited normally.
- A return code of 0xFFFFFFFD means that the worker process was killed.